# Write default code in lines in Java Eclipse on creating new project

Tags: java, eclipse

While solving coding competitions in java it becomes very tedious to write initialization of BufferedReader , PrintWriter and introducing variables (or copy pasting )every time I create a new project for a new problem. Is it possible in eclipse that when I create a new project I automatically get the template which already contains the variables introduced and initialized as described by me in the template. I looked for templates but wasn't able to figure out how to do it. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Window -> Preferences` and then `Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates` (or just paste `Code templates` into the Preference filter field).

Now expand `Code` and select `Class body`. Click `edit` and add your code.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for the `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Code Style` `Code Templates`.

if you want to write your own templates that should be available through content assist (ctrl + space) then you should take a look at `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Editor` -> `Templates`

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse there are many items under the *Source* menu that generate templated code for you.

Also if you right click on selected lines of code the popup menu also has a *Source* submenu and a *Refactor* submenu with content sensitive code generation options.